# trying to create a connection with my local mysql database on google colab

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, google-colaboratory, pymysql

```
!pip install PyMySQL
!pip install mysql-connector-python
from sqlalchemy import  create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://bisma:1234>@public_ip_machine/emoji_pwd")
import pandas as pd
query= 'select * from users'
df = pd.read_sql(query,engine)
```

I have tried it with my local machine ip address, got my public ip from https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/ and it gives me timeout error, when I use 127.0.0.1 it says OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") I have tried it with the port numbers as well, 'ip_address:3306' same error.

I read about configuring mysql for remote connections in other answers followed those steps
GRANT ALL ON emoji_pwd.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

there was no bind-address in my.ini file so I added bind-address=0.0.0.0
have restarted mysql service but it is still not working, can anybody help I want to create a connection with mysql database in my local machine using google colab. thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is your network.

```
     +----------------------------+                           
     |                            |                           
     |  +--------+          +---------+           +----------+
     |  |        |          |         |           |          |
     |  |  Mysql +----------+ Gateway +-----------+Google Col|
     |  |        |          |         |           |          |
     |  +--------+          +--+------+           +----------+
     |                      |  |  |                           
     |  +--------+          |  |  |                           
     |  | Host-1 |----------+  |  |                           
     |  +--------+             |  |                           
     |                         |  |                           
     |  +--------+             |  |                           
     |  | Host-2 |-------------+  |                           
     |  +--------+                |                           
     +----------------------------+
```

When you check the what-is-my-ip-address it shows the outgoing IP of the *Gateway*. If you use that in *Google colab*, it'll connect to your *Gateway*. This is not your MySQL server. Also, your *Gateway* doesn't know how to forward that traffic to the *MySQL* server. As there are other hosts inside the network.

**What do you need to do?**

1. Find the *Gateway* (sometimes it's the Router)
2. Configure it to forward the MySQL port to port X in the *Gateway*
3. Use the X port in *Google colab*

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, can you please tell me how i can carry out the steps that you have mentioned. thank you again

Comment: @habiba Please search in google with _how to port forward in DEVICE_. Here replace _DEVICE_ with router or device name and model number. 

Also, *accept* this as an answer if this answers your question.